# Permission Denied error along with a successful response from Google Speech transcription request

Tags: google-cloud-speech

The following NodeJS code handles Text-to-Speech successfully.
However, calling the `/transcribe` end-point for Speech-to-Text, returns a successful result , however, also throws an error:

```
STT ERROR:  Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
    at callErrorFromStatus (C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:192:76)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:360:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\resolving-call.js:99:78
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
for call at
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:160:32)
    at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\make-client.js:105:19)
    at C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\@google-cloud\speech\build\src\v1\speech_client.js:229:29
    at C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\normalCalls\timeout.js:44:16
    at LongrunningApiCaller._wrapOperation (C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\longRunningCalls\longRunningApiCaller.js:55:16)
    at C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\longRunningCalls\longRunningApiCaller.js:46:25
    at OngoingCallPromise.call (C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\call.js:67:27)
    at LongrunningApiCaller.call (C:\DevEnv\Projects\my-dream-team-tts\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\longRunningCalls\longRunningApiCaller.js:45:19)
    }
  ],
  totalBilledTime: { seconds: '4', nanos: 0 },
  speechAdaptationInfo: null,
  requestId: '5550510368443781709'
}
About to send back transribed text:  are you listening to me or not
```

This is the NodeJS code:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { TextToSpeechClient } = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
const { SpeechClient } = require('@google-cloud/speech');

const app = express();
const port = 3005;

const credentialsPath = process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CREDENTIALS;
console.log('credentialsPath: ', credentialsPath);
const credentials = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(credentialsPath, 'utf8'));

//TTS
const client = new TextToSpeechClient({
    credentials: {
        client_email: credentials.client_email,
        private_key: credentials.private_key,
    },
});

//STT
const speechClient = new SpeechClient({
    credentials: {
        client_email: credentials.client_email,
        private_key: credentials.private_key,
    },
});

const LONG_RECORDING_THRESHOLD_MS = 59000; //Up to 1 min - use the Google's STT recognize method

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});

/* TEXT-TO-SPEECH */


/* SPEECH-To-TEXT */
app.post('/transcribe', (req, res) => {
    console.log('**** Received a TRANSCRIBE request: ', req.body);

    const audioFile = req.body.audio;
    const duration = req.body.duration; //In milliseconds
    const encoding = 'BASE64';
    const sampleRateHertz = 48000;
    const languageCode = 'en-US';

    const request = {
        audio: { content: audioFile },
        config: {
            encoding: encoding,
            sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
            languageCode: languageCode,
        },
    };

    console.log('*** About to call speechClient with request: ', request);
    // Check audio length to decide which method to use
    if (duration <= LONG_RECORDING_THRESHOLD_MS) {
        speechClient.recognize(request)
            .then(handleResponse)
            .catch(handleError);
    } else {
        //WILL NOT WORK - this requires that the audio file is first uploaded to a storage bucket.
        speechClient.longRunningRecognize(request)
            .then(data => {
                const operation = data[0];
                return operation.promise();
            })
            .then(handleResponse)
            .catch(handleError);
    }

    function handleResponse([response]) {
        console.log('Handling successful transcribe result: ', response);
        const transcription = response.results
            .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
            .join('\n');
            console.log('About to send back transribed text: ', transcription);
        res.send({ transcription: transcription });
    }

    function handleError(error) {
        console.log('STT ERROR: ', error);
        res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
    }
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

The client (Angular) web app is passing a base64 transformed audio file that is captured here:

```
startRecording() {
  this.audioChunks = [];

  const stream = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });

  stream.then(audioStream => {
      this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(audioStream);
      this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event: { data: any; }) => {
          this.audioChunks.push(event.data);
      };

      this.mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
          const recordingDuration = Date.now() - this.recordingStartTime;
          const audioBlob = new Blob(this.audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });

          const audioBase64 = await this.textToSpeech.blobToBase64(audioBlob);

          const payload = {
            audio: audioBase64,
            duration: recordingDuration
        };         

          this.textToSpeech.transcribeAudio(payload).pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe(response => {
              console.log('Transcribed text upon FINISH:', response.transcription);
              this.chatService.chtPrompt.set(response.transcription);
              setTimeout(() => {
                //this.promptEnterClicked();
              }, 500);
          });
      };

      this.mediaRecorder.start();
      this.audioIcon = "pi pi-stop-circle";
      this.promptPlaceholder = "Recording";

      this.recordingStartTime = Date.now();
  });
}
```

*(When played-back in the browser for debugging, the captured audio file sounds great).*

This is how the NodeJS service is called:

```
transcribeAudio(payload: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/transcribe`, payload)
        .pipe(
            retry(0),
            catchError(this.handleError),
            take(1)
        );
  }
```

I followed the instructions on setting up the account, billing, credentials, service account - and using the json file as the GOOGLE_APP_CREDENTIALS.

The service account inherits from my only one project, with owner permissions.
I tried adding a specific permission for this service with the Cloud Speech Client, Cloud Speech Administrator permissions:

[image]

**Is there any specific permission I'm missing in the service account or something?**

**How is it possible that I receive both a successful response with transcripted text string, and a PERMISSION_DENIED error?**